# How do I delete keyframes on a plane track?

Tags: keyframes, tracking, dopesheet, graph-editor

I've got as plane track and I've keyframed the corners, however I want to delete some of the keyframes...they don't appear to be in in the dope sheet or graph editor. If I select the plane track and go to the frame (with the keyframe) and press the delete keyframe button (at the bottom of the UI) nothing happens.
Cheers
Jim

Comment: spacebar > delete keyframes or [alt + I]

Comment: HI, that seemed to delete all the keyframes....

Comment: I mean (Alt+ I) deletes all the keyframes, can I just delete a specific keyframe? Cheers

Comment: well if you go to the specific point in the timeline and delete them would that work?

Comment: That's what I tried, it deletes all the keyframes...

Comment: did you have the plane track selected?

Comment: What variable did you keyframe (location, rotations, scale or another slider)? :)

Answer (score 1):

Move The Green Timeline Marker On The Frame You Want to Delete The Keyframe on and press alt+I this will delete all current keyframes on that frame.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Move the timeline marker to the key frame you want it to delete by change the number, then hold `Alt` and `I` together.
[image]
Blender will ask if you would like to delete the keyframe.
Hope that helps